# Why and when use input type hidden?

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone explain about this field, why this is used and how it is interpreted????

```
<input type="hidden" name="msg" value="GATEFORUM|OE180187|NA|0.00|NA|NA|NA|INR|NA|R|gateforum|NA|NA|F|AMIT SINGH|9993523486|gis16|NA|NA|NA|NA|http://gis16.gateforum.net/online_enroll/payment_status.php|2482236435">
```

Comment: When `<form>` is submitted, the value of hidden is also passed.

Comment: When: in situations that you need to send information to the form handler (the file where the form is processed) that cannot be displayed to the user, or don't need to be displayed to the user. Why: because you need that information to process the form. Example: an user id, a post id, or something else that doesn't matter to the user but matters to the process. Got it?

Comment: Guys! It's not just for forms. Any time you need to store a value and you don't want it to be seen, you can store it (1) in a variable, (2) in localstorage, (3) in a session variable, or (4) in a hidden input field. I use these all the time, and I rarely use the `<form>` construct. It's really not needed any longer.

Answer (score 1):

It is used to pass data to the server when the form is submitted. The data is in the value attribute. As it is hidden the user can't see it, but the Server gets extra information about the form.